# How to fix "headers already sent" error in PHP?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

1. I'm not able to save response in PDF file generated from the APIs. I am using Jmeter for load testing and by the help of Jmeter I am calling the APIs.
2. In a Jmeter script I have 150 APIs. It's hard to go through all APIs to check the output. Is there any way to save the data generated by the APIs?

Comment: Your question title and question body contains different questions. Could you specify what do you need and separate your questions?

Comment: E.g I have 10 APIs, which i hit by using jmeter. Each API return Response data (E.g 
 Student Name with Roll Number). I want to save this response data(Student Name with Roll Number) in .CSV file because its hard to go through each Apis and check Response data.

Comment: Ok, good. So have you checked my answer with  "Save Response to a file"?

Answer (score 0):

To save response from API you have to add [Save Response to a file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener:

1. Right click on your API request.
2. Add -> Listener -> Save Response to a file.
3. Setup Variable Name containing saved file name.
   At this step you may enable "Add Timestamp" setting, then date will be included in file suffix following format `yyyyMMdd-HHmm_`

Check [JMeter Capturing Full Output](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/02/jmeter-capturing-full-output/) to get more information.